# Parsing TCP flag Data for IP Tables

Tags: iptables, firewall, tcp, nftables, flags

I have input file which has data like below

`chain:VARIABLE_IN ip_version:v4 proto:tcp sport:5401  dst_ip:18.159.158.206 dport:5432 decision:a   tcpflags:&syn!=syn`

My code reads above data to form Firewall rule like below:

`iptables -A VARIABLE_IN -p tcp  --sport 5432 -d 18.159.158.206 --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT --tcp-flags &syn!=syn`

Here `tcp flag` data is `&syn!=syn`. What is the meaning of this data and how to pass to firewall rule? This data for `tcp-flag` is coming in NFT temaplate, but i need to convert for IPTables format

Because iptables requires data in different format like `--tcp-flag FLAG1 FLAG2`

Comment: Where did this input file come from?

Comment: Input is coming from customer requirements

Comment: I don't recognize the format "&syn!=syn" and a google search terms up 0 results that contain that string, so without more information about where it came from, or unless you can get access to that the packets in a different format, you might be SOL

Comment: Actually there are two implementations. One with IP Tables and other with NF Tables. For both implementations, input data is same. NF Tables takes input as it is. It will `&syn!=syn`. But for IP Tables, this input data has to be parsed and need form rule in its format

Comment: @RobbieMckennie in words: after (bit) masking (the tcp flags) with `syn`, the value is not `syn`, where `syn` should be `0x02` (`0b10`); in "better" words: checks and checks only whether the `syn` bit is set, don't care about `ack`, `rst`, `fin` and so on. (Might be worth mentioning that, if `(tcp flags) & syn != syn`, then `(tcp flags) & syn` should/could only be equal to `0`, which is why either `! --tcp-flags SYN SYN` or `--tcp-flags SYN NONE` should do; well, unless `NONE` does not mean `0`)

Comment: @TomYan sounds like you're on top of it, but I don't follow how you get that from `&syn!=syn` and like I said I couldn't find information about this syntax anywhere